# When to choose serialQueue over concurrent queue in ios

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, concurrent-queue

I was asked to implement a thread safe dictionary in swift, I used the common approach:

```
 class MutableDictionary {
    var dictionary: [String : Any] = [:]
    var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue", attributes: .concurrent)
    
    func object(for key:  String) -> Any? {
        queue.sync {
            return dictionary[key]   
        }
    }
    
    func set(_ object: Any?, for key: String) {
        queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
            self.dictionary[key] = object
        }
    }
}
```

However, the following up question is:

1. What's the difference with using `concurrent` + `barrier` vs just using a `serialQueue` for setting in this case?
2. I did a testing on playground, I wrapped the get and set with 1000 time for loop, it turns out that the behavior for both serial and concurrent queue is almost the same.
3. Why the setting always raise an error?
   [image]
4. What does concurrent queue do better in this case (for both get and set) compared to a serial queue?
5. In iOS, when should I choose serial queue over concurrent queue? And vice-versa?

Comment: you are right, updated.

Answer (score 2):

1、with `barrier`, the concurrent queue is temporary able to execute one task at a time.
[image]

However, the serialQueue can only perform one task at a time.

2、Given you only use the queue to read/write, they obviously have the same effect. if you put another kind task to it, apparently the concurrent queue cost less and that is the real difference.

3、Submitted to async object address will be defined when your object is a class. You will have a bad address when you give the class member a new value, So you cannot access it and the error comes.
You can have a try by struct
.

4、refer to `answer 1`.

5、Sometimes when you want the task to be performed faster, concurrentQueue first. If you want to execute tasks orderly, serialQueue do the better.

Answer (score 2):

1. `concurrent + barrier` can run multiple `read` at the same time. `serial queue` can only run one task (read/write) at a time.
2. the results are the same, or even that the `serial queue` is better because you're using only one thread to run. You can only take advantage of the `concurrent + barrier` implementation when read/write operations happen on multiple thread/queue. In this case, the `serial queue` is better because you don't need to look and switch between queue/thread.
3. Full source code, please?
4. `Concurrent + barrier` might be better or not, as in (2), sometimes if you can ensure all operations happen in the same thread, then `serial queue` is better.
5. It depends on your case, as mentioned in (2), (4). One more thing about `concurrent + barrier`, sometimes it isn't a good choice as you think. Imagine:

- You're implementing a feature that needs to do a heavy write operation, for example, you're reading your dict and calculating a new value, and updating the dict. You wrap all of these steps in a `queue.async(flags: .barrier)` block.
- You expect these steps are running in your thread (background thread) and it doesn't block the main queue from reading the dict to update UI. But it does block the main queue, right? `Read` operations from the main queue have to wait for `barrier` block to finish first.
- If your application consumes a lot of CPU, you may have to wait for OS to find the thread for your `update` steps, which means you have to spend more time on it.

Comment: Thanks @nghiahoang. I'm not sure I understand the example you mentioned in #5: You expect these steps are running in your thread (background thread) and it doesn't block the main queue from reading the dict to update UI. But it does block the main queue, right? Why running on background thread is blocking main queue?

Comment: it's the behavior of `barrier`, you can see it in the image of @Elevo. The background thread (the thread you create inside your MutableDictionary) is the second row, main-thread is the first row, other thread is 3rd and 4th rows. When dispatch barrier is being run, all others have to wait for it to finish.

Comment: so in case, the write operations are used often and they're heavy operations, most likely the read operations will be blocked. 
One solution for it is that you can make an asynchronous version of the read operation, replace `queue.sync` with `queue.async`, and return back value from a callback.

Comment: you mean the concurrent queue i created is background thread? So thread and queue is identical?

Answer (score 2):

As @nghiahoang explained in their answer, the advantage of using a concurrent queue is that you can perform multiple 'get' requests simultaneously.

The reason you are getting a crash is because your `set` operation is using asynchronous dispatch along with a `barrier` in a tight loop.  When you submit a new `set` request before the previous request has completed, a new thread is required.  There are only a limited number of threads available.  Once you have exhausted the thread pool your app crashes.

I would suggest a couple of changes to your code to help with this.

The first is to bind your dispatch queue to one of the global dispatch queues, as this is best practice.

The second is to use `sync` in your `set` rather than `async`.  This will prevent thread pool exhaustion, but more importantly it ensures that once `set` returns that the dictionary has *actually been updated*. With `async`, the update will happen at some unspecified future time.

```
class MutableDictionary {
    var dictionary: [String : Any] = [:]
    var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue", attributes: .concurrent, target:.global(qos: .userInitiated))
    
    func object(for key:  String) -> Any? {
        queue.sync {
            return dictionary[key] 
        }
    }
    
    func set(_ object: Any?, for key: String) {
        queue.sync(flags: .barrier) {
            self.dictionary[key] = object
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so it looks like the error I got is caused by the "thread pool exhaustion"? I changed to your code above, the error is gone. But I just want to follow up on your answer here: What if my Set function has some heavy duty tasks that take long time, what's your recommendation ?

Comment: There is no one answer.  It depends entirely on what you are doing. A dictionary `set` operation should be computationally inexpensive and you can expect to perform a lot of them.  You also expect the dictionary to be in a known state at the end of the function call.  If you are performing some other sort of operation that is computationally complex or takes a long time then you need to design that solution so that it doesn't suffer from thread exhaustion.  For example, use an `OperationQueue` with a concurrent task limit.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> 1. What's the difference with using `concurrent` + `barrier` vs just using a `serialQueue` for setting in this case?

The former allows concurrent reads and the latter does not. But both are standard patterns for thread-safety.

FWIW, this “concurrent + barrier” approach is known as the “reader-writer” pattern. It features two key behaviors, namely that reads can happen concurrently (because it is a concurrent queue) and also that the caller does not have to wait for writes (because we invoke it with `async` with barrier).

> 2. I did a testing on playground, I wrapped the get and set with 1000 time for loop, it turns out that the behavior for both serial and concurrent queue is almost the same.

First, Playgrounds are not an ideal environment for testing subtle performance differences like this. Test in an app with a optimized, “release” build. (This also gives you the chance to debug with tools like the [“Thread Sanitizer”](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-memory-thread-and-crash-issues-early/).)

Second, you will only see very modest performance differences (probably only observable if doing millions of iterations, not thousands). But the overall behavior of these two patterns should be similar, as they are doing the same thing, namely synchronizing your access to this dictionary.

Third, your two `for` loops invoke this `MutableDictionary` from a single thread. If you are testing a thread-safe dictionary, I would suggest actually calling it from multiple threads. There is no point in introducing the thread-safety overhead if you are only accessing it from a single thread. E.g., this tests multithreaded behavior:

```swift
let dict = MutableDictionary()

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 1_000) { i in
    let result = dict.object(for: "\(i)")
    print(result)                          // this will always be `nil`, though, because your dictionary has no values yet
}

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 1_000) { i in
    dict.set("a", for: "\(i)")
}
```

[`DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2016088-concurrentperform/) is a parallel `for` loop.

> 3. Why the setting always raise an error?
>
> [image]

This is introduced by Playgrounds, probably its inability to handle the thread explosion of the unbridled dispatching of 1,000 asynchronous tasks. Try it in an actual app, not a playground, and the worker thread exhaustion will not result in this crash.

That having been said, you should probably avoid scenarios that permit thread explosion at all.

For example, if you really want to have a thread update 1,000 values in the dictionary, all from a single thread, you might provide a method that allows you to update multiple values with a single synchronization call. E.g.,

```swift
class MutableDictionary<Key: Hashable, Value> {
    private var dictionary: [Key: Value] = [:]
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue", attributes: .concurrent)

    func object(for key: Key) -> Value? {
        queue.sync {
            dictionary[key]
        }
    }

    func set(_ object: Value?, for key: Key) {
        queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
            self.dictionary[key] = object
        }
    }

    func synchronized(block: @escaping (inout [Key: Value]) -> Void) {
        queue.async(flags: .barrier) { [self] in
            block(&dictionary)
        }
    }
}

let dictionary = MutableDictionary<Int, String>()

dictionary.synchronized {
    for i in 0 ... 1_000 {
        $0[i] = "a"
    }
}
```

That updates the thousand dictionary values in a single synchronization. This simultaneously eliminates unnecessary synchronizations and solves the thread explosion issue.

> 4. What does concurrent queue do better in this case (for both get and set) compared to a serial queue?

Theoretically, the concurrent queue, “reader-writer” pattern, can offer better performance if you have an app that may be doing many concurrent reads simultaneously. Otherwise the overhead of the concurrent queue is unlikely not necessary/beneficial.

In practice, I have yet to encountered real-world scenarios where the concurrent queue was observably faster.

> 5. In iOS, when should I choose serial queue over concurrent queue? And vice-versa?

I would benchmark it for your particular use-case and see if the concurrent queue yields observable performance benefits. If so, the overhead of the concurrent queue might be worth it. Otherwise, you might want to stick with the simple serial GCD queue.

Generally, you will not see an observable difference. And where I have, I found that other approaches (e.g. `NSLock` or `os_unfair_lock`) were even faster. But if you are looking for a simple and robust synchronization mechanism, a serial dispatch queue is a good solution.

---

A few other observations:

- If creating a dictionary, I would be inclined to avoid the use of `Any`. We have a strongly-typed language and it is a shame to lose these benefits. E.g., you might make it a generic as shown in the example above with `Key` and `Value`.
- The wrapped dictionary should be `private`. It is imprudent to expose the underlying dictionary which would undermine the thread-safe interface.
- The synchronization mechanism (e.g., the lock or GCD queue or whatever) should be private, too.